# How to create an event based system in scala and play

Tags: scala, playframework

I want to be able to do something like this, say in Global or somewhere early in the application startup:

```
UserDao.beforeSave(someFunction)
```

Then whenever I save a user object like:

```
UserDao.save(user)
```

My someFunction will get called.

Is this possible and if so how should I go about modeling this type of behaviour?

This is to create an event based system for key points in the application, so developers can modify the system w/o having to change the core code base.

Comment: What does this have to do with event based systems? Also is `UserDao` something you would be writing?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Presumably you're writing `UserDao`, so why wouldn't you just put that functionality *in* `UserDao`?

Comment: @Ryan to allow for a plugable architecture where people can customize the application later on by just hooking into the events.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments above, if you really want to do something before the Save, perhaps that should be done in the `UserDAO.save` method. If not, then perhaps create a UserService.

If the *before* the actual save is not that important, you could use an Akka event you send. However, Akka event cannot guarantee, it will have before the save event.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to my question, not a different design :)   This is to allow for developers to hook into the lifecycle of the application and modify it w/o changing the core code base.  I would want before/after save events.  Hope that clears it up.